# Using .filter to remove an item from an array and return the new array

Tags: javascript, filter, indexof

I'm trying to return a new array by adding an event listener to my remove button. Connected to that event listener is a function which runs an `array.filter()` function. I'm not sure why it's not working. I can console.log the new array and that's fine, but when I try to return the new array, nothing happens.

I was splicing the item out of the array and that worked fine, but I wanted to try using filter. It seems that the logic is there and there's no error being thrown. But it just doesn't return a new array. It's the `removeIngredient` function that I'm trying to remove the item from via its index.

```
const removeIngredient = text => {
  const ingredientIndex = recipeOnPage.ingredients.findIndex(
    ingredient => ingredient.text === text
  )
  const ingredientList = recipeOnPage.ingredients
  const ingredient = ingredientList.filter(
    item => ingredientList.indexOf(item) !== ingredientIndex
  )
  return ingredient
}

const toggleIngredient = text => {
  const ingredient = recipeOnPage.ingredients.find(
    ingredient => ingredient.text === text
  )
  if (ingredient.included) {
    ingredient.included = false
  } else {
    ingredient.included = true
  }
}

const ingredientSummary = recipe => {
  let message
  const allUnchecked = recipeOnPage.ingredients.every(
    ingredient => ingredient.included === false
  )
  const allChecked = recipeOnPage.ingredients.every(
    ingredient => ingredient.included === true
  )

  if (allUnchecked) {
    message = `none`
  } else if (allChecked) {
    message = `all`
  } else {
    message = `some`
  }
  return `You have ${message} of the ingredients for this recipe`
}

const generateIngredientDOM = ingredient => {
  const ingredientEl = document.createElement('label')
  const containerEl = document.createElement('div')
  const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
  const ingredientText = document.createElement('span')
  const removeButton = document.createElement('button')
  recipeStatus.textContent = ingredientSummary(recipeOnPage)

  // Setup ingredient container
  ingredientEl.classList.add('list-item')
  containerEl.classList.add('list-item__container')
  ingredientEl.appendChild(containerEl)

  // Setup ingredient checkbox
  checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
  checkbox.checked = ingredient.included
  containerEl.appendChild(checkbox)
  // Create checkbox button in ingredient div
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggleIngredient(ingredient.text)
    saveRecipes()
    renderIngredients(recipeId)
  })

  // Setup ingredient text
  ingredientText.textContent = ingredient.text
  containerEl.appendChild(ingredientText)

  // Setup the remove button
  removeButton.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>'
  removeButton.classList.add('button', 'button--text')
  ingredientEl.appendChild(removeButton)
  // Create remove button in ingredient div
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeIngredient(ingredient.text)
    saveRecipes()
    renderIngredients(recipeId)
  })

  return ingredientEl
}

const renderIngredients = recipeId => {
  // Grab the ingredient display from the DOM
  const ingredientList = document.querySelector('#ingredients-display')
  ingredientList.innerHTML = ''
  const recipe = getRecipes().find(item => {
    return item.id === recipeId
  })

  // Iterate through the list of ingredients on the page and render all items from recipeDOM
  recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => {
    const ingredientDisplay = generateIngredientDOM(ingredient)
    ingredientList.appendChild(ingredientDisplay)
  })
  saveRecipes()
}
```

Nothing is happening, as I mentioned above. When I console.log the variable `ingredient`, I get the new array with the removed item gone, but when I return it, nothing happens.

Comment: That is a lot of code to comb through . Can you reduce it to a [mcve] so it's easier to find the problem code?

Comment: You're not storing the returned array anywhere. Where exactly are you expecting the new array to be used? Also, don't omit the semicolons, it will lead you to a hard-to-debug bug, sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the structure correctly, your `removeIngredient` can probably be trimmed down to:

```
const removeIngredient = text => {
  recipeOnPage.ingredients = recipeOnPage.ingredients.filter(i => i.text !== text);
}
```

This removes the `ingredient` which has it's `text` property same as the `text` parameter. You are doing of a lot of unnecessary `findIndex` to get the `filtered` ingredients and return it. But you're nowhere setting it back to the `recipeOnPage` object.

Since you aren't using the return value of `removeIngredient`, you need not return anything